urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0 DataPDU XSD
I'm looking for the XSD of urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0 namespace included the DataPDU document. Where can I download it?
Thank you
<Saa:DataPDU xmlns:Saa="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
  <Saa:Revision>2.0.13</Saa:Revision>
  <Saa:Header>
    <Saa:Message>
      <Saa:SenderReference>12345678</Saa:SenderReference>
      <Saa:MessageIdentifier>pacs.008.001.08</Saa:MessageIdentifier>
      <Saa:Format>MX</Saa:Format>
      <Saa:SubFormat>Input</Saa:SubFormat>
      <Saa:Sender>
        <Saa:BIC12>XXXXXXXXXXXX</Saa:BIC12>
      </Saa:Sender>
      <Saa:Receiver>
        <Saa:BIC12>YYYYYYYYYYYY</Saa:BIC12>
      </Saa:Receiver>
    </Saa:Message>
  </Saa:Header>
</Saa:DataPDU>


What has this got to do with the programming language Swift or even programming for that matter?
